# Two ArrayList manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I have one ArrayList in Session, lets say for example `[305,306,380]`.

On submit, user choice other products which i save them in 2nd array, for example `[390,305,480,380]`

How can i make another three arrays where

1. All new values `[390,480]`
2. All values which are in both lists `[305,380]`
3. All values from list1 which are not in list2 `[306]`

I need this in ASP.NET 4.0 C#

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ArrayList.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb.aspx) to get arrays against your arraylists. Then using LINQ you can easily get what you want with[`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) an [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) methods, for example

```
array2.Except(array1)
array1.Except(array2)
array1.Intersect(array2)
```

**Edit: Complete Code**

According to your requirement, your code may look-like this;

```
        ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList(new int[] { 305, 306, 380 });
        ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList(new int[] { 390, 305, 480, 380 });

        int[] array1 = (int[])arrayList1.ToArray(typeof(int));
        int[] array2 = (int[])arrayList2.ToArray(typeof(int));

        //1. All New values
        int[] uniqueInArray2 = array2.Except(array1).ToArray();

        //2. Common values
        int[] commonValues = array1.Intersect(array2).ToArray();

        //3. Values of arrayList1 which are not in arrayList2
        int[] uniqueInArray1 = array1.Except(array2).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry I was away from my system for a long time. I have added the complete code. Hopefully it will help!

Answer (score 2):

Use [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) the folowing way:

```
var first = new HashSet<int>();
first.Add(...);

var second = ...;

1. second.ExceptWith(first);
2. first.IntersectWith(second);
3. first.ExceptWith(second);
```

Comment: When you do `second.ExceptWith(first);` `second` gets element which are in `first` removed from it